# Quasar unit testing for vue3

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, quasar

I am using quasar for developing a vue app. I am using vue 3.0.7. I have installed jest and created the jest.config File.

The jest config file contains the following:

```
clearMocks: true,

  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "ts",
    "vue"
  ],
 
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
  
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
  },

  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "\\\\node_modules\\\\",
    "\\.pnp\\.[^\\\\]+$"
  ],
```

I am writing the following test for a demo vue component:

```
import { shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils"
import  ComponentVueTest from "./ComponentVueTest"

describe('ComponentVueTest', ()=>{
    test("Text shoudl be in the html" , () => {
        let wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentVueTest);
        expect(wrapper.html).toContain('JustTesting');
    })
})
```

The component that is being tested:

```
<template>
  JustTesting
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        
    },
})
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

and also the package.json dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.1",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.6",
    "cordova": "^10.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-loader": "^16.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.0.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing": "^1.0.3",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest": "^2.2.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.12",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7"
  },
```

When i run  the npm run test ("test": "npx jest") i get the following error:

```
FAIL  src/__tests__/Demo.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Vue.defineComponent is not a function

    > 1 | import { shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils"
        | ^
      2 | import  ComponentVueTest from "./ComponentVueTest"
      3 |
      4 | describe('ComponentVueTest', ()=>{

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js:7856:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/Demo.spec.js:1:1)
```

I have been trying for hours to fix it and can't seem to understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try changing: 
`import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'` 
to 
`import { defineComponent } from 'vue'`

Also looks like you need to change your `wrapper.html` to `wrapper.text()` and add `toMatch` rather than `toContain`, that said the following should work:

```
import { shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils"
import  ComponentVueTest from "./ComponentVueTest"

describe('ComponentVueTest', ()=>{
    test("Text should be in the html" , () => {
        let wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentVueTest);
        expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch('JustTesting');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to unit testing vue3 in quasar v2 is to use  @quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest. Just install it with

```
quasar ext add @quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest
```

and it should set up everything for you. Notice it is still in alpha and some components are not fully working yet(for me QPage wasn't working).
Hope this helps somebody :)